# Display latest date from a HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, date

I currently have several classes which contain a date inside an attribute.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="date" date="19/11/2013"></div>
  <div class="date" date="06/11/2013"></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

What I would like to do, is find the latest date and display it on the page. So far, I've found the information in the attribute, checked that it doesn't exist in the array then and pushed it into an array. I'm not entirely sure of the best approach from here, but ideally i would like to find the latest date and then append it to the results container.

```
$('.date').each(function () {
    var dateArray = [];
    var date = $(this).attr('date');
    if ($.inArray(date, dateArray) == -1) {
        dateArray.push(date);
    }

    $('#result').append(dateArray);
});
```

Any assistance on the above would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hey oGeez - Thanks for responding :). In my test environment, the code above appends both individual dates. So hopefully that aspect works. I just need the latest date if possible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid as `date` is not a valid attribute. If you need a custom value in an element, use a `data-*` attribute:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="date" data-date="19/11/2013"></div>
    <div class="date" data-date="06/11/2013"></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

To compare dates in JS you need to convert them to `Date` types, however you need to split the constituent day/month/year parts as the date is in UK format. Try this:

```
var dates = $('.date').map(function() {
    var dateArr = $(this).data('date').split('/');
    return new Date(dateArr[2], dateArr[1] -1, dateArr[0])
});
$('#result').append(new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dates)));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/RGcq3/1/)

Comment: Thanks Roy, appreciated. I cannot get the above to work in my codepen, but I've had a look at the fiddle. I would like UK dates if that's possible? I notice that when i change the first number in the attribute to 01, it's classed as February, "00" seems to work for January.

Comment: @Tron sorry, that's my mistake. Months are zero based in the Date constructor. I've updated my example

Comment: No need to apologise, I really appreciate the help here! :) - Ok great, I have this up and running now. Lastly, what's the best way to change the output of the date, if possible, I would like the output to appear in this format: 11/11/2013 - Again, really appreciate your time on this.